# Also, Dude, [nomenclature] is not the preferred nomenclature

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We already have a tag for this,

- [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

I suggest we make [nomenclature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) a synonym for [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

Comment: Why on earth would we need any of those tags? The tag wiki for terminology is ridiculous.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not so sure. Almost 2k questions. All of them about terminology. Only question is whether any of them are on-topic but I'm not gonna touch that

Comment: Looking through https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate , I do not readily see any violations for [tag:terminology] if it's made to mean "questions about the meaning or usage of programming terms".